# Changing mariadb port

Tags: mariadb, configuration

I'm trying to change the default port for mariadb to 52000. I've modifed the port in /etc/MySQL/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf and restarted the service. However, each time it still starts up on the default port.

I'm running Debian. Is there another config somewhere that I need to modify?

Answer (score 2):

The right configuration is:

```
port = 52000
```

under a `[server]` or `[mysqld]` section.

Your most likely problem is that either you are modifying a configuration file that is not being included, or it is being included, but other file is overriding your config (last parsed option wins). Look for other files containing the port definition and delete them, or make sure they are read in the right order.

To check which mysqld config files are applied, you can run `mysqld --verbose --help` to verify which config files are read. More suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-configuration-file-is-being-used